# MySQL :: The addition of JSON column makes SELECT queries non-performant (when temp tables are needed)

Tags: sql, mysql

I added a JSON column to a table in MySql that holds a small amount of data (~about 7Kb) for each row. The table has roughly 135K rows. Prior to this addition, all my queries on this table executed in well under 1 sec. Now, however, when `explain` notes a temporary table was needed to for the results, the query takes roughly 7 secs. Does anyone one know why a JSON column would cause such a performance issue?  If I change the column to TEXT, the same query run under 1 sec. It stands to reason the JSON column will grow in size... should I pull out this column into another 1:1 table? And would this be an issue if eventually we start querying by values in the JSON column?

It's worth noting that:

- I am not querying the JSON column nor am I returning it in the results.
- This table is searched by users is various ways so writing an index for every possible scenario to eliminate the use of temporary tables is not practical.
- Most queries are dynamically created via the application Hibernate ORM code

For example, the query below takes 7 secs to complete with a JSON field, but under 1 sec as a TEXT field.

```
SELECT 
    xaction.XactionId, xaction.PropStreet, xaction.PropNum, xaction.PropStreetUnit
FROM
    Xaction xaction
        INNER JOIN
    Team team ON xaction.TeamId = team.TeamId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    AppUser appuser_primaryAgent ON xaction.AppUserIdPrimaryAgent = appuser_primaryAgent.AppUserId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    AppUser appuser_coAgent ON xaction.AppUserIdCoAgent = appuser_coAgent.AppUserId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    AppUser appuser_assistant1 ON xaction.AppUserIdAssistant1 = appuser_assistant1.AppUserId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    AppUser appuser_assistant2 ON xaction.AppUserIdAssistant2 = appuser_assistant2.AppUserId
WHERE
    team.TeamId = 1
        AND (
            appuser_primaryAgent.AppUserId = 1 
            or appuser_coAgent.AppUserId = 1 
            or appuser_assistant1.AppUserId = 1 
            or appuser_assistant2.AppUserId = 1
        )
GROUP BY xaction.XactionId
ORDER BY PropStreet , PropNum , PropStreetUnit
```

Explain

```
+----+-------------+----------------------+------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+-------------------------------------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table                | partitions | type   | possible_keys                                                                                                                                                                                            | key     | key_len | ref                                       | rows  | filtered | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+----------------------+------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+-------------------------------------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | team                 | NULL       | const  | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                                                                                  | PRIMARY | 8       | const                                     |     1 |   100.00 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | xaction              | NULL       | index  | PRIMARY,IDX_PropNum,IDX_PropStreet,AppUserIdPrimaryAgent,AppUserIdCoAgent,XactionPropTypeId,XactionSourceId,XactionStatusId,IDX_PropNum_PropStreet_PropStreetNum,AppUserIdAssistant1,AppUserIdAssistant2 | PRIMARY | 8       | NULL                                      | 49515 |    10.00 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | appuser_primaryAgent | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,AppUserId_idx                                                                                                                                                                                    | PRIMARY | 8       | afdata_next.xaction.AppUserIdPrimaryAgent |     1 |   100.00 | Using index                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | appuser_coAgent      | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,AppUserId_idx                                                                                                                                                                                    | PRIMARY | 8       | afdata_next.xaction.AppUserIdCoAgent      |     1 |   100.00 | Using index                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | appuser_assistant1   | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,AppUserId_idx                                                                                                                                                                                    | PRIMARY | 8       | afdata_next.xaction.AppUserIdAssistant1   |     1 |   100.00 | Using index                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | appuser_assistant2   | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,AppUserId_idx                                                                                                                                                                                    | PRIMARY | 8       | afdata_next.xaction.AppUserIdAssistant2   |     1 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index                     |
+----+-------------+----------------------+------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+-------------------------------------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
6 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

And for reference, the table definition is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `xaction` (
  `XactionId` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `PropNum` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `PropStreetDir` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PropStreet` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `PropStreetUnit` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `City` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `State` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Zip` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `County` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MlsId` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TaxId` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GfNum` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ListPrice` decimal(13,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ListPriceOriginal` decimal(13,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SqFt` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `SqFtSource` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Beds` smallint DEFAULT NULL,
  `Baths` decimal(4,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `YearBuilt` smallint DEFAULT NULL,
  `LotSize` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Schools` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Subdivision` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LockBoxId` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LockBox` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SecurityCode` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `HoaFee` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `HoaFrequency` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Occupancy` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Remarks` mediumtext,
  `Instructions` mediumtext,
  `ListOtherInfo` mediumtext,
  `ContractPrice` decimal(13,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `OtherParty` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EarnestMoney` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DueDiligenceFee` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Concessions` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Financing` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SpecialProvisions` mediumtext,
  `ContractOtherInfo` mediumtext,
  `Possession` mediumtext,
  `EffectiveDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `ClosingDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `ListDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `ExpireDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `ClosedDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `XactionPropTypeId` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `XactionSourceId` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `XactionSide` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `XactionStatusId` bigint NOT NULL,
  `PercentageCommission` decimal(6,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CommissionNote` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SplitTeamLead` decimal(6,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SplitPrimaryAgent` decimal(6,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SplitCoAgent` decimal(6,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SplitAssistant1` decimal(6,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SplitAssistant2` decimal(6,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PayoutEstimated` decimal(13,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PayoutActual` decimal(13,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PayoutReferral` decimal(13,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PayoutBroker` decimal(13,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PayoutTeamLead` decimal(13,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PayoutPrimaryAgent` decimal(13,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PayoutCoAgent` decimal(13,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PayoutAssistant1` decimal(13,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PayoutAssistant2` decimal(13,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ExpensesBroker` decimal(13,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ExpensesTeamLead` decimal(13,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GeoLatitude` decimal(9,7) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GeoLongitude` decimal(10,7) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GeoLocatorStatus` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TimeZone` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `FieldDataJson` text,
  `CreateDateTime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `EditDateTime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `TeamId` bigint NOT NULL,
  `AppUserIdPrimaryAgent` bigint NOT NULL,
  `AppUserIdCoAgent` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `AppUserIdAssistant1` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `AppUserIdAssistant2` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`XactionId`),
  KEY `IDX_PropNum` (`PropNum`),
  KEY `IDX_PropStreet` (`PropStreet`),
  KEY `AppUserIdPrimaryAgent` (`AppUserIdPrimaryAgent`),
  KEY `AppUserIdCoAgent` (`AppUserIdCoAgent`),
  KEY `XactionPropTypeId` (`XactionPropTypeId`),
  KEY `XactionSourceId` (`XactionSourceId`),
  KEY `XactionStatusId` (`XactionStatusId`),
  KEY `IDX_PropNum_PropStreet_PropStreetNum` (`PropNum`,`PropStreet`,`PropStreetUnit`),
  KEY `AppUserIdAssistant1` (`AppUserIdAssistant1`),
  KEY `AppUserIdAssistant2` (`AppUserIdAssistant2`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Xaction_AppUser_Assistant1` FOREIGN KEY (`AppUserIdAssistant1`) REFERENCES `appuser` (`AppUserId`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Xaction_AppUser_Assistant2` FOREIGN KEY (`AppUserIdAssistant2`) REFERENCES `appuser` (`AppUserId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Xaction_AppUser_CoAgent` FOREIGN KEY (`AppUserIdCoAgent`) REFERENCES `appuser` (`AppUserId`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Xaction_AppUser_PrimaryAgent` FOREIGN KEY (`AppUserIdPrimaryAgent`) REFERENCES `appuser` (`AppUserId`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Xaction_XactionPropTypeLookup` FOREIGN KEY (`XactionPropTypeId`) REFERENCES `xactionproptypelookup` (`XactionPropTypeId`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Xaction_XactionSourceLookup` FOREIGN KEY (`XactionSourceId`) REFERENCES `xactionsourcelookup` (`XactionSourceId`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Xaction_XactionStatusLookup` FOREIGN KEY (`XactionStatusId`) REFERENCES `xactionstatuslookup` (`XactionStatusId`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: Can you please run `SELECT VERSION();` and report what it says?

Comment: @BillKarwin 8.0.35

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have an index (or a foreign key defition) for the TeamId which is the one that is likely to limit the query data. The optimizer choose to build a temporary table for that.

Btw, your `GROUP BY` does not match the columns you have in `SELECT`. The `GROUP BY` is used usually with aggregate functions and it should contain all non-aggregated columns from your `SELECT`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I did add the FK and it runs under 1 sec now (not sur why that wasn't already done??).  However, I am not sure this solves the issue when a temp table might be necessary. I will need to run a few more tests.

Comment: Also, the `group by` was needed as an alternative to `distinct` which was less performant.  The ORM queries were returning duplicates and this was the method to solve that.

Comment: If you want to remove the duplicates, use `DISTINCT`. When your `GROUP BY` statement contains only some of the non-aggregated rows, MySQL is allowed to pick any row that has specific `XactionId`. Also, that use of  `GROUP BY` is only allowed on old MySQL or when the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` option is disabled. You should keep the option enabled.

Comment: You can `GROUP BY xaction.XactionId` as the other columns in the projection are all functionally dependent on the PK (`XactionId`).

Comment: @user1191247 True

Comment: So far with my testing I have yet to experience a huge lag in query results by adding the TeamId FK relationship.  Oddly, this is present in production.  Not sure how it was removed in the dev environment.  Many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

**Redesign the schema.**

- A "property" and a "transaction" are two separate Entities; they should be two tables.  Perhaps there can be multiple transactions for a single property.  A 1-many relationship could exist -- property_id as a column in the Transaction table.
- Or can it be the other way around -- a single transaction involves several properties?  This would necessitate a many-to-many table connecting the two Entity tables.
- Instead of having 4 tables for 4 types of people, have a single table with an extra column to indicate primaryAgent, etc.  Then there would be one `JOIN` and a single test for `AppUserId = 1`.  Many of the decimal columns would move into the [up to] 4 rows in the new table.

I also recommend moving "sale" information to a separate table.  There would not be a row in that table until the sale occurred.  Meanwhile, `LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL` can determine that the property has not yet sold.  Also, if there could be multiple sales, that new table could have multiple rows.

As you restructure the tables, rethink the indexes and foreign keys.

It is unclear whether you need the `GROUP BY` after these changes.

**GROUP BY**

Since there are no aggregates, the `GROUP BY` seems like a waste.  On the other hand, I think the restructure will obviate the need for the grouping.

**Optimization**

- `OR` is a big performance killer
- The entire table must be read to produce the result.
- By having a single person table and search it by `AppUserId = 1`, this should avoid 99% of the effort of the query.

Comment: I appreciate the ideas on restructuring - this is something we may look into. I realize "or" searches are killers, but the query example given is just an example. Because the user can define custom searches, there could be any number of scenarios where the query changes to have many "or" statements.  This is out of our control unfortunately.

Comment: Isn't it true though that the OR statements may be implemented on an internal table after mysql uses an applicable index?  For example, no single Team in our platform would have more than 2000 xactions which would greatly reduce the expense of a full table scan.

Comment: @Burton - `OR` turns into `IN` _if_ the tests are on the same column in the same table.  That helps somewhat.  Another technique for `OR` is to use `UNION`, but that requires a major rewrite of the query, which seems beyond the scope of the question.